# Win32 api different classes per window?

Tags: c++, oop, winapi

ive recently started to work with the win32 api and im trying to do a couple of things. 
I have a project that is gonna use about 4-5 windows. I want to seperate each of these into a different cpp file where each has its own message Loop. How do i pass information from window to window?(is there some sort of entry point?) at the moment im creating all windows during `case WM_CREATE:` and I am showing them as required.

I am trying to have a nice OOP design but having trouble with that, my main issue is the communication between windows. I have a fair amount of experience in C# and C++ and other than this the win32 api is not being a problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may also want to look at the Get/SetWindowLongPtr functions (specifically the GWL_USERDATA field). This gives you somewhere to store a 'this' pointer for each window.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want a per-window message *loop*, unless you want each window in its own thread. You probably need a window *procedure* instead.

Each window class has its own window procedure, which you register by setting `lpfnWndProc` field of `WNDCLASS` structure before passing it to the [RegisterClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Once you've done that, you can use that class when creating a new window with [CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In your case, you'll probably want to implement the window procedure so it accepts custom messages (`WM_APP + x`), and then pass custom messages between windows using [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for asynchronous communication) or [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for synchronous communication). If necessary, you can create separate window classes and window procedures for your different windows. A single message loop is capable of pumping messages to all these procedures.

Comment: `WM_APP+x`, actually (application messages). The `WM_USER+x` range is for use **within** a private window class.

Comment: @MSalters You are correct, thanks! In my defense, it's been quite a few years since I've done this ;)

Answer (score 1):

The classic way of inter-window communication is sending / posting messages:

[SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)